# Prove that if removing 3 vertices from a connected graph results in a connected graph, then there exists a 3-fan to those 3 vertices

Tags: graph-theory, examples-counterexamples

This is a proposition from lecture that I'm trying to prove:
[image]

However, consider the following graph

[image]

where set A is indicated by the yellow vertices. If we remove this set from the graph B, then B - A is still connected. However, we can't choose any vertex x in V(B)\A such that there is a 3-fan from x to A. This is obvious, because one of the vertices in A is only accessible through the other two vertices, so there can't be a fan to that group of vertices.

Am I misunderstanding the Lemma here, or is it incorrect? If it is correct, how would I prove it?

Thank You

Edit: The above lemma was incorrect. It was meant to be that all vertices in A must be adjacent to a vertex in V(B)\A. The proof is 
[image]

Comment: Why do you define $Q_2$ and $Q_3$ and never mention them again?

Comment: @bof: I'm not sure. This was the proof provided by the professor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your understanding of Lemma and counterexample. So I think there is something wrong with Lemma formulation.